# unable to get substitute() to replicate :s

Tags: regex, vim, substitution

Contract name to be parsed out. of following types

Parse following:

```
./contracts/SimpleStorageContractInstance.vy
SimpleStorageContractInstance.vy
```

To:

```
SimpleStorageContractInstance
```

using %s works

```
%s/\v([^/]+)\.vy$/\1/
%s/\v(\/|^)@<=(\w+)\.vy$/\2/
```

but
tried following with substitute in fucntion script and doesnt work

```
substitute(a:contractName,'\v([^/]+)\.vy$','\1',"")
substitute(a:contractName,'\v(\/|^)@<=(\w+)\.vy$','\2',"")
```

Comment: Could you format your sample text ("from" and "to") properly?

Answer (score 0):

Dunno why the -2, anyway this worked

```
matchstr(a:contractFilePath,'\v(\/|^)@<=[a-zA-Z]+\.vy$')->substitute('\v^(\w+)(\.vy)','\1','')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it solved the problem.